# Wordpress White Screen of Death

Tags: php, wordpress

One of my client's site was taken down by hosting as it was sending spam, the site was working fine before it was taken down by hosting, I downloaded the wp-content folder from Cpanel and full dump of database. When I run the site at localhost, it shows the blank page on all directories. When I use the dumped database, it goes blank but when i change it to fresh WP database, the sites looks fine, so it means there is some problem or mis configuration on database? I started debugging manually and found that the file wp-blog-header.php is not getting this file

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

Because I added echo "Oh God why?"; in template-loader.php and it was not showing the result while with the fresh integrated database, it shows the result.

Can someone please give suggestion that what could be the problem in database?

Comment: It's probably the setup.. check your `config` file and make sure it's pointing to the correct database. Then, make sure your database has the correct site url - `localhost/whatever` instead of `www.yoursite.com`

Comment: I have changed the wordpress home url path in wp-options to localhost/mysite and still the problem is same, now the hosting has again reactivated my website and now even on live site, the screen has gone blank. Again on live site, Blog URL and wp-config.php and DB settings are fine

Answer (score 1):

Your live WP site and your local one will (should) use two separate databases.

1. In your *local* **phpMyAdmin**, make sure you've imported the exported database from the live site.
2. In your `wp-options` table, change `siteurl` to `http://localhost/yourpath/toWP`.

   *This should be pointing to your actual 
   Wordpress folder.*
3. Locate the `wp-config.php` in your actual WP folder, and make sure the `WP_HOME`, `WP_SITEURL`, `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, and `DP_HOST`

All of this has to match up to your **local** setup, otherwise it will fail (WSOD).

If this doesn't work, it's possible the person that set it up changed some things to make it hard to maintain without him/her. I've seen it done. Personally, I detest WP  for things other than blogs. It has a lot of security problems, constantly needs updates, and allows people that really shouldn't be doing web design to toss something together with templates and call it "professional". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically changing the domain of your WordPress installation from www.example.com (the original domain) to www.example.local (your localhost).

I usually use this procedure to move WP from a domain to local:

- Download from WordPress site the corresponding version of WP and install it on local.
- Overwrite the new db with your backup
- Change wp-config.php to point to the backup db (only if config changed, i.e. table prefix)
- Follow one of the many guides to move WP to a new domain. [Example 1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), [Example 2](https://yoast.com/move-wordpress-blog-domain-10-steps/) and change the db fields to your local domain (www.example.local).
- Restart your local apache

It should now be ok to login and regenerate permalinks.

Comment: I have changed the wordpress home url path in wp-options to localhost/mysite and still the problem is same, now the hosting has again reactivated my website and now even on live site, the screen has gone blank. Again on live site, Blog URL and wp-config.php and DB settings are fine

Comment: File permissions on the WP files are ok?

Comment: I think my client hired some other WP expert and his site is working again. Thanks for your help :)